# putImageData / Canvas - How do I dump the pixel array in here?

Tags: javascript, graphics, html, canvas, pixel

How do I redraw the pixel array after I after I have previously used getImageData? The way that I thought made sense gives me the error: *An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12*

```
function makeImage(canvasId, background, object) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var backgroundData = null;
    var objectData = null;

    //Get image Data
    function getDataFromImage(img) {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0 ,0);
        return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    }

    //Load image
    function loadImage(src, callback) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onload = callback;
        img.src = src;
        return img;
    }

    //Get Background Image Data
    var backgroundImg = loadImage(background, function() {
        backgroundData = getDataFromImage(backgroundImg);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
        });

    //Get Object Image Data
    var objectImg = loadImage(object, function() {
        objectData = getDataFromImage(objectImg);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });

    main();

    function main() {
        ctx.putImageData(backgroundData, 0, 0); //Try to redraw the background??
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to put the

```
main()
```

call inside the loadImage call that is populating backgroundData. It could be that main is called before the image has loaded.

```
var backgroundImg = loadImage(background, function() {
    backgroundData = getDataFromImage(backgroundImg);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    main();
});
```

Comment: spot on. thanks that was driving me mad! that explains all the problems in my actual project now, just calling before things have loaded. cheers.